# With a Large output, clicking Show all or Show more freezes Mathematica

Tags: output, crash

Running the following code takes about 30 min on my laptop (everything before the `Reduce` is instant) and produces a `Large output` that Mathematica does not display, only shows buttons `Show more`, `Show less`, `Show all`, `Set size limit`. Clicking any of these buttons freezes Mathematica and for a while the rest of the computer as well. A dialog with `Force quit`, `Wait` appears in Mathematica, but is also unresponsive.

When I got it to display, even selecting that cell caused a 10 second slowdown and closing the cell about 1 minute, with `Force quit`/ `Wait` messages. The output did not print to file using the OpenAppend suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741432/exporting-mathematica-print-output-to-a-txt-file).

How to see more output without crashing Mathematica? I currently don't have an alternate computer to try this on.

Using version 11.3, 
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory      : 16318MB (3910MB used)
Machine Type        : Laptop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

```
Clear[pi1, pi2, foc1, foc2, d, vs, d1, d2, p1, p2, q, c, hess, dpdq, \
dfocdq, dpdqsub, dDvs, dDp1, ddDvs, ddDp1, foc1sub, foc2sub, Dvs, \
Dp1, soc1sub, soc2sub]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < p1 < p2 < q && q > 1 && 0 < c < p2 && 
   Flatten@Thread[0 < {d, pi1, pi2}];
vs = (p2 - p1)/(q - 1);
d1 = d[p1] - d[vs];
d2 = d[vs];
foc1 = D[p1*d1, p1];
foc2 = D[(p2 - c)*d2, p2];
hess = D[{foc1, foc2}, {{p1, p2}}];
dfocdq = {{D[foc1, q]}, {D[foc2, q]}};
dpdq = -Inverse[hess].dfocdq;
dpdqsub = 
  dpdq /. {Derivative[1][d][(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> dDvs, 
    Derivative[1][d][p1] -> 
     dDp1, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> 
     ddDvs, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[p1] -> ddDp1};
soc1sub = 
  hess[[1, 1]] /. {Derivative[1][d][(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> dDvs, 
    Derivative[1][d][p1] -> 
     dDp1, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> 
     ddDvs, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[p1] -> ddDp1};
soc2sub = 
  hess[[2, 2]] /. {Derivative[1][d][(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> dDvs, 
    Derivative[1][d][p1] -> 
     dDp1, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> 
     ddDvs, (d^\[Prime]\[Prime])[p1] -> ddDp1};
foc1sub = 
  foc1 /. {Derivative[1][d][(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> dDvs, 
    Derivative[1][d][p1] -> dDp1, d[(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> Dvs, 
    d[p1] -> Dp1};
foc2sub = 
  foc2 /. {Derivative[1][d][(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> dDvs, 
    Derivative[1][d][p1] -> dDp1, d[(-p1 + p2)/(-1 + q)] -> Dvs, 
    d[p1] -> Dp1};
Reduce[
 dpdqsub[[2, 1]] < 0 && dDp1 < 0 && dDvs < 0 && 
  ddDp1 \[Element] Reals && ddDvs \[Element] Reals && 
  0 < p1 < p2 < q && q > 1 && 0 < c < p2 && foc1sub == 0 && 
  foc2sub == 0 && 0 < Dvs < Dp1 && soc1sub < 0 && soc2sub < 0]
```

Comment: It might be useful to check `LeafCount` and `ByteCount` of the expression. If it is particularly huge, maybe saving to a file in `InputForm` and opening in a text editor would be better. The formatting code can require considerable time and memory for large expressions.

Comment: Not much I can do with the file, even opening it freezes Mathematica. The size of the notebook was 448 MB. After deleting the offending output, 7 MB.

Comment: The FE is an unreliable POS. Try not to visualize anything with it. Only try to show something if you can be _absolutely certain_ it won't crash Mathematica. If you use Mathematica as a legitimate tool, not a toy, this becomes something you always have to keep in mind.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What is FE and POS? I am unfamiliar with these acronyms.